# Quarter function in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written the "select" query for the quarter function in SAP HANA.

```
select QUARTER (CURRENT_DATE, 8) FROM DUMMY;

output: 2021-Q3
```

Can someone please help me with the equivalent query in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lukasz points out the second parameter is the *start_month* [SAP doc's](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/20e62fe875191014b78bd015a16966fb.html)

So this is really two parts, to know what [year-quarter](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html#usage-notes) something is with respect to an offset, you just need to subtract the `offset month`, from the `date` you have and then `year` and `quarter` the adjusted date. AND formatting the STRING

The later point it seems cannot be done with one [TO_CHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html) with a format command. otherwise it would be really nice. So for now we will have to stick to `YEAR(adj_date) || '-Q' || QUARTER(adj_date)`.

### The long winded explaining SQL:

```
SELECT
    8 as first_month_of_fin_year
    ,first_month_of_fin_year - 1 as month_adj
    ,to_date(column1,'yyyy-mm') as in_date
    ,dateadd(month,-month_adj, in_date) as adj_date
    ,year(adj_date) as y
    ,quarter(adj_date) as q
    ,y::text || '-Q' || q::text as answer
FROM VALUES
  ('2021-06'),
  ('2021-07'),
  ('2021-08'),
  ('2021-09'),
  ('2021-10'),
  ('2021-11'),
  ('2021-12'),
  ('2022-01'),
  ('2022-02'),
  ('2022-03'),
  ('2022-04'),
  ('2022-05'),
  ('2022-06'),
  ('2022-07'),
  ('2022-08'),
  ('2022-09'),
  ('2022-10')
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

| FIRST_MONTH_OF_FIN_YEAR | MONTH_ADJ | IN_DATE | ADJ_DATE | Y | Q | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-06-01 | 2020-11-01 | 2020 | 4 | 2020-Q4 |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-07-01 | 2020-12-01 | 2020 | 4 | 2020-Q4 |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 2021-Q1 |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-02-01 | 2021 | 1 | 2021-Q1 |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-03-01 | 2021 | 1 | 2021-Q1 |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 2021-Q2 |
| 8 | 7 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-05-01 | 2021 | 2 | 2021-Q2 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-01-01 | 2021-06-01 | 2021 | 2 | 2021-Q2 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 2021-Q3 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-03-01 | 2021-08-01 | 2021 | 3 | 2021-Q3 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-04-01 | 2021-09-01 | 2021 | 3 | 2021-Q3 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-05-01 | 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 2021-Q4 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-06-01 | 2021-11-01 | 2021 | 4 | 2021-Q4 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-07-01 | 2021-12-01 | 2021 | 4 | 2021-Q4 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 2022-Q1 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022 | 1 | 2022-Q1 |
| 8 | 7 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-03-01 | 2022 | 1 | 2022-Q1 |

### Smaller SQL

So a smaller/compact SQL can be written once we see what steps we are following as:

```
SELECT
    8 as start_month
    ,to_date(column1,'yyyy-mm') as in_date
    ,year(dateadd(month,-(start_month - 1), in_date)) || '-Q' 
        || quarter(dateadd(month,-(start_month - 1), in_date)) as answer
FROM ...
```

or if you know you only want 8, and `current_date`

```
SELECT
    year(dateadd(month,-7, current_date)) || '-Q' 
         || quarter(dateadd(month,-7, current_date)) as answer
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try any of these:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
     , QUARTER(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
     , YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) || '-Q' || QUARTER(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: This missing the effect of the `8` which moves time back by 8 months. Thus today `2022-02` gives the answer `2021-Q3` as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to handle second argument indicating start month of fiscal year.

```
QUARTER (d, [, start_month ])
```

For current date(2022-02-06) the output should not be `2022-Q1` but `2021-Q3`.

It could be achieved with some date computations:

- first part is handling year(current/previous)
- second part is computing quarter adjusted with start month

Query:

```
SET FirstMonth = 8;

SELECT  YEAR(d) - IFF(d >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d),$FirstMonth,1), 0, 1) 
        || '-Q' || QUARTER(DATEADD(month, -$FirstMonth+1, d)) AS output
FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS d) AS sub;
```

Output: `2021-Q3`